# QFile is not reading nor opening my file

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

I have a file called "sequence_30.dat" that contains a sequence of 1 and -1 in a vertical representation (i.e.: each 1 or -1 is in a separate line) .. I am trying to read the file for another operation using the following code:

```
int length = 31
QFile file("sequence_"+ (static_cast<QString>(length)) +".dat");
if(file.exists()){
  file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
  if(file.isOpen()){
    ....
    ....
  }
  file.close();
}
```

but when debugging, the compiler skips the "`if(file.exists())`" statement and when it is removed the compiler again skips the "`if(file.isOpen())`" statement

I am very sure that path is correct, but if is not how to make sure that I am in the right path (i.e.: is there is a way to check where am I reading from) .. and if the path is correct why my file is not opening ?

Comment: You can check where you are reading by printing the result of QDir::currentPath()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
static_cast<QString>(length)
```

Should be:

```
QString::number( length )
```

You can check it by just printing it out to the console:

```
cout << qPrintable( QString( "sequence_" ) +
        QString::number( length ) + ".dat" ) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

[static_cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c36yw7x9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) doesn't work that way, so instead of a static_cast, you should use [QString::number](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#number-4) to convert an *int* into a *QString*.